# Prove that a $\kappa : G/G_{s} \to G.s$ is a bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I have to prove that given an action this function $\kappa : G/G_{s} \to G.s$ is a bijection.

$$  G/G_{s} \to G.s$$
$$gG_{s} \to g.s$$
Where $G$ is a group and:

$G_{s}:=\{g \in G : g.s=s\}$(Isotropy group)

$G.s:=\{g.s: g \in G\}$(Orbit)

then I need to prove that $\kappa$ is surjective and injective, but I dont know if there is a better way to prove this because I think I will complain me doing this proof by showing that  $\kappa$ is surjective and injective. Can you help me to prove this please? Thank you.

Comment: How is $\kappa$ defined?

Comment: OOO thank you I forget it :) I m sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $g_1.s=g_2.s\Rightarrow (g_1)^{-1}g_2.s=s\Rightarrow (g_1)^{-1}g_2\in G_s\Rightarrow g_1G_s=g_2G_s$[This comes from the condition of equality of two cosets]. So it is injective. Surjective is obvious from the defination[Because for any $g.s\in G.s \exists gG_s\in G/G_s$ s.t $\kappa(gG_s)=g.s$].

Comment: thank you @user152715, Then with this we are done isn't ? :)

Comment: Can you tell me why is it obvious that $\kappa$ is surjective please ? thank you

Comment: An this implication please: ⇒g1Gs=g2Gs :) thank you

Comment: See now. I have added something.

Comment: ok let me check :)

Comment: thank you @user152715 then that is why is obviuous :) but what is that definition yo are talking about ?

Comment: Do you know what is a coset?

Comment: yes is this definition: $gH:=\{gh:h\in H\}$

Comment: Then prove from the definition that $aH=bH$ iff $a^{-1}b \in H$. If you can't then study any basic books thouroughly. Then try to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: ok thank you But that is why the implication isnt?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: ok thank you a lot then this proof is done :)

Comment: Yeah. you are right.

Comment: If you have understood then you can approve my answer.

Comment: Yes of course :) because I LIKE YOUR PROVE :)